# Prevent child of child going out from MDI Parent Form

Tags: c#, winforms

How to prevent child.child.Windows going out from MDI Parent Form.

Please see following image.

[image]

Add Product Window is a child of MDI Parent Form. Add Category Window is child of Add Product Window. Add Product Window is not going out from MDI Parent Form as I use following code.

```
Add_Product obj_AddNewProduct = new Add_Product();
obj_AddNewProduct.MdiParent = this;
obj_AddNewProduct.Show();
```

But how can I make obj_AddCategory child of MDI Parent Form?

```
Add_Category obj_AddCategory = new Add_Category();
// obj_AddCategory.MdiParent = this; ???
obj_AddCategory.Show();
```

Or anyone has better solution?

Comment: I know you want to constrain that Category form, but it looks like a Dialog form, so use `obj_AddCategory.ShowDialog` to make it modal.  Otherwise, it would be `obj_AddCategory.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
Add_Category obj_AddCategory = new Add_Category();
obj_AddCategory.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
obj_AddCategory.Show();
```